# why i got this warning "rule cannot be matched" in my Lexer Program

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, lex

I have this code in flex program ".l"

```
"if" {return IF;}
"else" {return ELSE;}
"For" {return FOR;}
. {printf("SYNTAX ERROR .. EXIT ..");exit(0);}
```

and this code in bison program ".y"

```
%token IF ELSE FOR
```

but i got that error of

```
warning, rule cannot be matched
warning, rule cannot be matched
warning, rule cannot be matched
```

Comment: Is that all the code in your lex file? And which rules are the ones that can't be matched?

Comment: @sepp2k no i have more simple rules like Idf and + - * / and others but only the if else and for are not working

Comment: Then please post a minimal version of your code that, when run through flex, produces the same warnings that you're getting. And please also post the full output of `flex` including the line numbers of the warnings (when run on the minimized version of the code, otherwise the line numbers won't match). It is very likely that one of the rules you didn't show conflicts with the ones that aren't working (in fact it is quite possible that in the process of creating the minimal example you will already find the issue yourself).

Comment: @sepp2k sorry to bother you ... i found the problem its in my writing of the code , i did like this "if" space { new line return IF; } ... as soon as i wrote the code on a single line it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem

i needed to write the code on a single line like this

```
"if" { return IF; }
```

and not like this

```
"if" {
    return IF;
}
```

Comment: Both of those options work perfectly fine. Also the code you posted initially has the actions on a single line already.

Answer (score 0):

I feel it depends on the version of lex you are using.

In the version that I am using right now (`flex 2.6.4`), all three syntaxes work perfectly fine, even with a newline.

But an older version threw an error when writing it on a single line
`"if" {return IF;}`. It was solved after padding `return IF;` with white spaces as `"if" { return IF; }`.

Comment: exactly , it was a writing issue !! thnx for your response